# Big-Oh notation question

Tags: real-analysis, logarithms, asymptotics

When we have a question like so:

What is the smallest integer $n$, such that $f(x) = x^{5.7}(\log x)^{1.2}$ is $O(x^n)$?

Would we go about the question as so: round up $x^{5.7}$ to become $x^6$.
Since $\log x < x$, we can treat the $\log x$ as $x$, and
$\rightarrow x^6x = x^7$, so the smallest integer $n:
7$

Is this correct?

Comment: You've shown $7$ works, but you haven't shown it is minimal.  Clearly $5$ doesn't work.  What about $6$?

Comment: For this problem, it would be useful to consider the order of $x log(x)$ relative to the orders of $x$ and $x^2$.

Comment: I don't see how 6 could work, since we can't simply ignore the log term, correct?

Comment: Compute $$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x^{5.7}(\log x)^{1.2}}{x^6}$$  If you do not already know how to do this, why not learn?

Answer (score 1):

That $\log x < x$ is insufficient—after all, we also have $x/2 < x$, but $x/2$ is, by construction, $\Theta(x)$. You need the fact that $\log x = o(x)$.

Comment: So is 7 not the correct answer then? And how do we prove that logx = o(x)?

Comment: I made no comment about what the correct answer is. To figure out how one might show that $\log x = o(x)$, refer to the definition of little-oh.

Comment: By definition of little-oh, we need to show that the ratio log(x)/x approaches zero as x goes to infinity. Doing calc, we see that limit when x approaches infinity log(x)/x results in zero. Is this enough to prove that log(x) is o(x)?

Comment: Yep, that does it

Answer (score 0):

For positive $a,b$ let set $f(x)=\dfrac{\ln(x)^a}{x^b}$ it is not to difficult to see that $f\searrow$ at infinity.

Indeed $f'(x)=\dfrac{\overbrace{\ln(x)^{a-1}}^{>0}(\overbrace{a-b\ln(x)}^{<0})}{\underbrace{x^{b+1}}_{>0}}<0\quad$ for $x$ large enough.

In particular since $f$ is continuous and $f(x)>0$ for $x>1$ we can conclude that $f$ is bounded (*it is decreasing so cannot go to positive infinity, has a lower bound zero so cannot go to negative infinity, hence bounded*). $$\exists M>0\text{ : }|f(x)|<M\quad\forall x>1$$

Now we just plug $x=u^2$ and use the logarithm multiplicative to additive property to show that the denominator is negligible.

$$f(x)=f(u^2)=\dfrac{2^a\ln(u)^a}{u^bu^b}=\dfrac{2^af(u)}{u^b}\le \dfrac {2^aM}{u^b}\to 0\quad\text{when }u\to\infty$$

> As a consequence $\ln(x)^a=o(x^b)$ for any positive $a,b$

Since the logarithm at any power is negligible as long as $x$ is sufficiently large, we can simply bound $$\ln(x)^{1.2}=o(x^{0.1})=O(x^{0.1})$$

> Therefore $x^{5.6}\ln(x)^{1.2}=x^{5.6}O(x^{0.1})=O(x^{5.7})=O(x^6)$

And $6$ is the minimal integer that is greater than $5.7$.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $t \ge 720$. Then
$$
{\rm e}^t  = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{t^n }}{{n!}}}  \ge \frac{{t^6 }}{{720}} \ge t^5  \Longrightarrow t \ge \log (t^5 ).
$$
Suppose that $x \ge 720^5$, and take $t = x^{1/5}$ in the above inequality to get
$$
x^{1/5}  \ge \log x \Longrightarrow x^{0.24}  \ge \log ^{1.2} x.
$$
Therefore,
$$
x^{5.7} \log ^{1.2} x \le x^{5.94}  \le x^6 
$$
provided $x \ge 720^5$.